# Using Str_replace to remove info from an outputted invoice

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have seen plenty of examples on how to do this with preg_replace, but I wasn't sure if preg_replace had been discontinued and replaced with str_replace ??.

Anyway on each of my invoice fields I have a stock level that has the same sort of pattern :

```
 - (99 In Stock) -
```

So each line has a stock level similar to above, what I want to do is replace that with just :

```
 -
```

so basically replace everything inbetween - and - with just one -

Does anyone know how this can be done with str_replace, or what the best command to do it with it is ?.

Comment: `I wasn't sure if preg_replace had been discontinued and replaced with str_replace ??.` Any evidence of making this statement?

Comment: As when I had posted something about preg replace in the past I was told not to use it as it was out being discontinued

Comment: See this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_replace is very much here and for a purpose too. Use this call:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/-[^-]*-/', '-', '- (99 In Stock) -' );
```

Or make it more strict:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/-\s*\(\d+ In Stock\)[^-]*-/', '-', $str);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, the problem is 99 are not always in stock, there could be any amount in stock.

Comment: You can pass any other value in `$str` above like `(50 In Stock)`.

Comment: This is what the orginal looks like : Bridestone Pt34 - 175/55/18/W/63 - (99 In Stock) - £22.48 Each After I use the above it looks like this Bridestone Pt34 - (99 In Stock) - £22.48 Each,     so its removing the part before the (** in stock) for some reason.

Comment: Im using $description1 = preg_replace('/-[^-]*-/', '-', $row['description1'] );

Comment: Try: `$repl = preg_replace('/-\s*\(\d+ In Stock\)[^-]*-/', '-', $str);` which will give this output: `Bridestone Pt34 - 175/55/18/W/63 - £22.48`

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Just to let you know this wouldn't have been possible without use of regex and hence `preg_replace` :P